# Is the following set of vectors orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\left( \begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}\\\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\0\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix} \right)$

So what I initially did is check the dot product of all the possible pairs of matrices? So I found v3 and v4, v1 and v4 and v2 and v4 are orthogonal? Is this correct? If so, where do I go from here?

(I labeled the vectors v1-v4 respectively)

For something to be orthonormal the dot product between every vector in S is zero AND the norm(magnitude) of each vector in S is one, correct? So this wouldn't be orthonormal because all the pairs of vectors aren't orthogonal?

Comment: What means rad3 etc?

Comment: radical symbol I am so sorry didn't know syntax for mathjax

Comment: You simply have to check the dot product, or even easier, put $A$ equal to the matrix having $v_1,\dots ,v_4$ in the columns, then if $AA^{T}=Id$ the vectors are orthonormal. (Why?) Also do you mean $\sqrt{10}$ instead of $rad10$? The radical of an integer also exists, but I doubt that is what you want here.

Comment: the dot product of all 4 vectors at once? and yes I meant the square root.

Comment: To display $\sqrt2$ write `$\sqrt2$`. More generally, for other formatting questions, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: orthonormal = pairwise orthonormal

Comment: Is that first vector correct? It has two components equal to $1$, which means that its norm is obviously something greater than $1$, so you can’t have an orthonormal set no matter which pairs are orthogonal. I suspect that the last two components should be $frac1{\sqrt{10}}$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonals pairs are {v1,v4}, {v3,v4} only

Comment: Also $v_2$ and $v_4$, which OP already discovered, but I agree there are no others.

Comment: Yes. I missunderstand original "rad" form of formulas